# Car microphone; very low signal

Tags: microphone, preamp

I would like to use a car microphone for bluetooth communication.

The mic is a BMW one: [84316938762](https://www.google.com/search?q=84316938762).

The wiring diagram (TIS) marks the mic's two connectors for the pin 1 and 2: [TIS](https://www.newtis.info/tisv2/a/en/e46-330ci-cab/wiring-functional-info/body/communication/telecommunications/fixed-installation-siemens-handset/hands-free-mode/microphone/jnFLel6) (X18507).

However measuring with oscilloscope on these pins, there is pretty much nothing. (Measuring in AC mode, 5-10mV range).

How can I use this microphone? (If I need a pre-amp, please post some schematics, or a specific recommendation).

The BT module which I'm using is [BC127](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwidq9nfou_jAhV-AxAIHZgeCewQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.semak.com.ar%2FItem%2FFile%2F3342%3Ffilename%3DBC127%2520PTS_r1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1AoSvyQK2CM5KnpI3s8jPZ), there is not too much info about the microphone's requirements.

Comment: Ask asked, this question is too road to be answered here.

Comment: The link to the microphone is just a search link. You should link to an actual part datasheet.

Answer (score 3):

This microphone is most likely an Electret mic.  This requires a DC bias for the FET amplifier inside the mic capsule.

Use a quiet (noise-free) DC power supply in the range of 3-5 Vdc with a 2200 Ohm resistor in series from the supply to the mic (+) line.  The DC supply ground is connected to the mic ground.

Use a coupling capacitor to pass the mic signal to your preamp (or scope).  The value of the capacitor depends on the input impedance of your preamp.

Use a scope to observe the signal.  This will give you an idea of how much gain you need in your preamp.

A typical electret mic has an output around -50 dBu to -40 dBu when held close to your mouth and speaking at a nominal level.  Obviously, level is much lower if your are attempting to pick up a voice that is several feet away.

Comment: Thank you! How is the 2.2K calculated? Is there some guidelines or formula? I don't have any datasheet for this microphone unfortunately.

Comment: Bias resistor value is not critical. Pretty much any value from 1k to 10k will work, depending on the bias supply voltage. 2200 Ohms is a reasonable compromise with a 3V to 5V supply.